# Strange UINavigationBar behavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

In my app, I have a window tintColor that sets everything to be tinted red. a user presses a bar button item (red items) on the root view controller and it presents a UIModalPresentationSheet with a navigation bar (red nav items). Upon pressing a button on *that* navigation item, it pulls up a full Modal View, now this modal view also has a navigation bar but all the navigation items are gray; they are usable, and still run the correct function, but their color is gray. Any idea why? At first I tried doing this programmatically with gray buttons, then I did it through storyboarding and tinted the nav items directly in the scene and they looked red, yet at launch, they were grey on the Modal View. Can anyone tell me why??

Here is how the modal view is presented:

```
- (void)barButtonItemPressedOnUIModalPresentationSheet {

    asdfVC *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showAsdf"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The weird thing is that I set the nav tint, the button tint, even the view tint in the correct VC class, yet it seems to completely ignore it. Could it be because I set a navigation bar on it *before* presenting it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the color for the entire application with the `appearance` property.
Set it in AppDelegate and the UI will look on all views same.

To set the `tintColor` to red use:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor redColor];
```

and

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor redColor];
```

You can also check out following code for even more customization:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a property of UINavigationController in your AppDelegate.h class.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

In your AppDelegate.m class write the code below in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  method

```
self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.UIModalPresentationSheet];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

Now write this code in the ViewDidLoad method of your UIModalPresentationSheet  class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: I don't have a UIModalPresentationSheet in my app delegate, so it gives me an error "property UIModalPresentationSheet not found on object of type appdelegate."

Comment: Your UIModalPresentationSheet is a ViewController type ? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Can you try set tint colour on your view Controller and on your navigation bar where it shows green:

```
viewController.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Thats the weird thing!!! I do have this set in my class yet the buttons are gray!!! Could it be that i'm setting the nav bar before actually presenting the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this exact same anomaly in my application and have tried all of the things you've tried. I've put the code to make the color blue (in my case) in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear and nothing seems to fix it. My guess is it's an IOS bug.

Comment: very unfortunate. I have filed a bug report to apple, lets hope it gets fixed soon!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Apple assumes that we won't present more than 1 view controller and dims the background and ALL bar button items (not sure why) as default behavior to put focus on the frontmost view.

To fix this, you just need to force the tintAdjustmentMode to Normal on the app's window in DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
self.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```